# Decrypting ASPNET_Membership Password

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption

I am trying to decrypt my password stored in `aspnet_membership` table...

I am using the following code,

```
Dim encodedPassword() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)
encodedPassword = MyBase.EncryptPassword(encodedPassword)
Dim decryptedPassword() As Byte = MyBase.DecryptPassword(encodedPassword)
If (decryptedPassword IsNot Nothing) Then
  Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedPassword, 0, decryptedPassword.Length)
End If
```

but at the line of `DecryptPassword(encodedPassword)` it shows error as

> "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid."

Comment: You can not decrypt the password if it was encrypted by one of the built in `MembershipProvider`s.

Comment: @Eranga - For the default provider it depends on the passwordFormat setting. By default it's "hashed", but can be set to "encrypted".

Comment: @PHeiberg You are correct. Forgot about the `passwordFormat` option.

Comment: @Arasu R - Have you implemented your own provider or why are you subclassing an existing provider. Have you tried using the default sql provider and decrypted the password directly using the Decrypt method?

Comment: BTW, I should mention that it's generally a bad idea to store passwords in a form that can be decrypted.

Comment: my customer want it in that way....

Comment: I have tried first encoding method then decoded,its working fine in this case...but if i directly decode the value from database then only it throws error....

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to Base64 Decode it first:

```
byte[] encodedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(pass);
byte[] bytes = this.DecryptPassword(encodedPassword);
```

or in VB.NET:

```
Dim encodedPassword As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(pass)
Dim bytes As Byte() = Me.DecryptPassword(encodedPassword)
```

**Edit:** As @Eranga pointed out, this is provided that the MembershipProvider used actually supports decryption and for the default provider the [passwordFormat setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.passwordformat.aspx) controls if it's "hashed", "encrypted" or "plain". By default the setting is "hashed", which means no decryption possible.

Encrypted passwords are base64 encoded before being saved to the database and for that reason they need to be decoded before being decrypted.